# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Subscription without an ID):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

What am I doing wrong here?

**My checkout controller is as below:**

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
  def create
    subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])

    if subscription.nil?
      redirect_to root_path
      return
    end
    respond to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def success

  end

  def cancel

  end
end
```

It comes up with error:
**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Subscription without an ID):**

but when I print the Subscription id on the index page, it shows up fine,

```
<h1>All Subscriptions</h1>

<% @subscriptions.each do |subscription| %>
  <%= subscription.id %>
  <h3><%= subscription.name %></h3>
  <p>Price: <%= number_to_currency subscription.price_cents / 100.0 %></p>
  <p><%= subscription.description %></p>
  <%= button_to 'purchase now', checkout_create_path, method: :post, remote: true  %>
<% end %>
```

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @subscriptions = Subscription.all
  end
end
```

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, :description, :price_cents, presence: true
  validates :price_cents, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
end
```

Comment: Probably just need to supply the subscription instance in `checkout_create_path`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the id in the route. The error happens because `params[:id]` is `nil` since it isn't provided.

```
<%= button_to 'purchase now', checkout_create_path(subscription.id), 
     method: :post, remote: true  %>
```

or, depending on your setup

```
checkout_create_path(subscription_id: subscription.id)
```

and in the controller

```rb
subscription = Subscription.find(params[:subscription_id])
```

Comment: Thank you @Eyeslandic for the reply. That fixed it.  I changed the syntax very slightly to:  ```checkout_create_path(id: subscription.id)``` on the index page,  and  ```subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])```  on the controller